# How to use scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset to ensure only stops scrolling at two possible positions?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I want my vertical UIScrollView to stop only at the max content offset if the user scrolls up or the min content offset if they scroll down.

I am using the following two function

```
func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint,
                         withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x:0,y:self.scrollView.contentSize.height - self.scrollView.bounds.height)
}
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

        if velocity.y > 0 {
            targetContentOffset.pointee.y = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.height
        } else { 
            targetContentOffset.pointee.y = CGFloat(0)
        }
}
```

The first function is never called. The second one is called properly when I scroll up or down, but setting the pointee.y value doesn't seem to change the contentOffset - I can still scroll and stop in the middle for instance. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add view over scrollview and add swipe gesture, like this:

```
 var swipeGesture  = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
    let directions: [UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction] = [.up, .down]
    for direction in directions {
        swipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeView(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)
        swipeGesture.direction = direction
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        view.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
    }


    self.view = view
    scrollView.delegate = self


@objc func swipeView(_ sender : UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    if sender.direction == .up {
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.height), animated: true)
    } else if sender.direction == .down {
         scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't add a swipe gesture. It would interfere with the collectionView that my scrollView is on top of (its in each cell).